# Unable to click on pop up screen

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

After entering values to few fields i click on submit button which produces a pop up screen where i should click go button. I tried below code, it worked once but not working now. Please help

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 6); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lets_go']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='lets_go']")).click();
```

How to fix ?

Comment: What do you mean not working now?? is there exception??

Comment: Please share your error that you're getting so we can have more of an idea of what the problem is!

Comment: Element is not visible error

Answer (score 0):

If it's an alert the use:

driver.switchto().alert().accept().

If pop up is a window, then first switch to that window using *WindowHandler*, then click on element

Comment: I have added the screen...plz let me know to handle as i am new to selenium

Answer (score 0):

[`ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) is used for checking that an element is present on the `DOM` of a page and visible, if this condition true within given time limit, it returns `WebElement` otherwise throws `TimeOutException`, So There is no need to find element again, omit last line and try as below :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 6); 
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("lets_go")));
el.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pasting the snippet of code for that "popup" to get your code working along with stack trace of error you are getting.

Also, you can go through http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/handle-alerts-popups-selenium-webdriver-selenium-tutorial-16/. It gives you clear idea when it comes to handling popup.